# Meteor (JavaScript App Platform) | Adding Data to User Accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

After successfully adding the "account-ui" & "accounts-password" packages using the *METEOR* platform, I encountered difficulties in attempting to implement the 
*todo* app.

How do I add user data?

More specifically:

- Declaration of a variable named *points* upon an instance of a user
  signing-up, and assigning this variable a value equal to zero.
- Ensuring visibility of the *points* variable from within the template.
- Implementing a button that incrementally enlarges the font size by
  five points while updating the template to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would try to avoid updating the 'users' collection frequently, so I'd store that information in a separate collection. But since this is not what you asked, here's how you store a default value in a user document.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  user.profile = {points: 0};
  return user;
});
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

Comment: How to display this data ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too broad. I suggest you to read a tutorial for Meteor. https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app